# Kotlin using coroutines from worker thread to wait & get something from UI Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say you are in a `WorkerThread` performing a long-running task. But, in order to complete said long-running task, you must get *something* from the `UI Thread`.

Basically, I need to access the **UI Thread** which will generate an object that MUST be initialized on the UI thread but then can be used in any thread.

What I would like to do is possibly use coroutines / suspended functions where the worker thread actually waits for an operation on the UI Thread completes.

How can I achieve such a thing ? Thanks !

The following represents a schema of what I intend to achieve:

```
@WorkerThread
fun processTask() {
    // ... do some stuff to init work
    val something = getSomethingFromUiThread() // wait
    // ... resume & complete stuff with "something"
}

@MainThread
suspend fun getSomethingFromUiThread() {
    // ... create object on UI Thread
    // ... return initialized object to the worker thread
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 5):

You can try something like this:

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { //Your Main UI Thread
              val myuithreadobject = myobject()
               withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
               //this is out background thread
                        nodelist = ArrayList()
                       val info = myuithreadobject

                       printAllViews(info)

                    }
              //after background thread is finished
        //do work on main thread
            }
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's almost that. I have edited my question to add a schema. The constraint that I have, is that I am in a method called on a worker thread. Not the other way around.

Comment: With this solution how can we communicate between two coroutines? How can we send and receive messages between two coroutines. It is just using other coroutine's context inside the first one for that section of code to execute

Comment: Actually I think @mr-patel got it right, because I managed to create my `getSomethingFromUiThread` with `GlobalScope.async(...).wait()` but the method calling this method must also be suspendable. But I cannot do that, I am overriding a method from a parent class. So anyway, I think his answer is the right one. I'll validate it once I get it working. Unless there is a way to have a real blocking method ? But then, it's no longer about coroutines...

Answer (score 0):

Using `Dispatchers.Main` and `Dispatchers.IO` might allow you to use different contexts, but we need to understand that starting a new coroutine is not as starting a new thread. Coroutines are light weight threads. And for communication you need to use some concept called as `Channels`. Please refer this [link](https://proandroiddev.com/kotlin-coroutines-channels-csp-android-db441400965f).

Similarly using channels you can link a coroutine in thread to a coroutine on another

Answer (score 0):

Just implement **CoroutineScope** in your class and  define variable in your class as

```
 private val job = Job()
 override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
 get() = job + Dispatchers.Main
```

and now you can do as in your class:-

```
launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    val data = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // do your work in background thread
    }.await()
    //And now data return on UI thread
}
```

Example :-

```
    Class MyClassFragment: Fragment(), CoroutineScope {
private val job = Job()
override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = job + Dispatchers.Main

override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

    launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        val data = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // do your background operation
        }.await()
        //And now data return on UI thread
    }
}

}
```